# how to count number of items in an array android

Tags: java, android, arrays

How can I count the number of items in an array in android?

here is the code that dose not work

```
if (vehicleList.length = 1){
     //do something                  
                     }
```

can anyone help?

Comment: D: in java use '==' to compare...

Comment: of course!!!! i was being soooo stupid! sorry for the question!

Comment: Related info: For type arrayList use ".size()"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use == for comparison..

```
if (vehicleList.length == 1){
     //do something                  
 }
```

Comment: duuuu!!!! thank you so much i was being so stupid!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a value to vehiclelist.length. Use `==` instead which will compare the two values.

Answer (score 0):

if vehicleList is an `arrayList` the try like this

```
if (vehicleList.size() == 1){
     //do something                  
}
```

Comment: -1 For comparison you need to have == not single =